# Why do I get screen flickering when playing some games?

Tags: windows, windows-10, graphics-card

See video here: https://streamable.com/7c7r4i

In this example, whenever I move click my mouse in game the task bar flashes. Any idea what the cause of this issue is? I have a 360hz monitor and a 2080ti gfx card.

Comment: Did you try updating BIOS (firmware) and Video Driver?

Comment: I already did do that

Comment: Provide a screenshot of the graphical settings for the application focusing on the resolution information and whether or not the window is full screen or in window mode.

Comment: https://ibb.co/LdZdXMK

Comment: Your title says you see this in "some" games. What are the other games you are seeing this with?

Comment: What I notice in the video is that for a brief moment the window goes from full screen to windowed mode and back, as if another process spawns and stops, a popup shows or an external program interacts with the game. Do you maybe run the app Borderless Gaming, an app that forces any game full-screen?